Grout cracking inside shower
4 months after a full remodeling of the bathroom the grout in the shower floor is cracking and getting chipped.
The contractor who did the job says it's normal and it's the house movement. He wants to use the same grout material (Prism Ultimate Performance grout) to fix it, just adding more grout to it. The rep at Daltide (where we bought it) says it's the wrong material (although that's not what he said when he sold it to us) for a shower and we should remove all the grout, let the area completely dry, and then use siliconized caulking.
It's only in the shower floor area where it gets wet, no cracks in the rest of the bathroom.
What should I do?


Is this in the middle of the shower floor, or in the corners where it meets the wall? If the contractor says it's normal, what is his plan to make it different this time around?

What is under the tile? Any deflection caused by a person standing will cause plain grout to crack.

It's in the corners with the shower wall and the shower step where the door is. Not sure what he plans on doing differently. Also not sure why wouldonly be where the shower floor is, if it was related to the house movement I imagine I'd see cracks in the rest of the bathroom grout.

under the tile there is hot mop

What is under the hot mop, plywood?

Please clarify if this is IN the shower or OUTSIDE of the shower. Your picture appears to be outside the shower. If it's also in the shower please post a picture. That looks like wood, caulk would be appropriate.

@Platinum Goose, That's outside the shower,  you're seeing from outside the step that leads inside the shower. it is wood-like tile made of porcelain. The white piece to the right is the door frame and is wood. there are other cracks inside the shower and outside the shower around the edge where the floor meets the step, but this is the only spot where it's not just a crack but the grout is chipping and "leaking" (the corner on the floor was initially white and now is brown as the grout is sedimenting there)

Vertical tile that meets horizontal tile can be grouted but that grout will in most times fail.
I see two issues here.

Just the use of grout... I will come back to this.

The grout area was so thin that the grout couldn't adhere to the thinset and pushed out.


Most tile guys just caulk (silicone) this line.    I firmly believe in grouting it first.    The grout however should be inset of the two tiles meeting not outside of the tiles - which is what your picture shows.    I would then apply the silicone caulk in a small bead and if I apply it right it should bond with both the grout and both tiles - in my experience this is a much better bond than just the two tiles with a gap.
To fix this you are going to have to scrape out the grout really well.    This won't be an easy task where this is and how thin it is.    After that I would try again to add grout to the crack.   If I can get a 1/4" in there that should be plenty.    Once the grout cures (few days), I would apply silicone.    Meaning you need to keep this dry 3-4 days straight.

Cracking of grout is caused by movement.  There are certain areas where movement is very hard to avoid.  Usually these are where tile meets something else.  For example, the line between a countertop and a backsplash, between a bath and the wall, between a door casing and the wall.  Anything near the latch side of a door can crack eventually from vibrations from the door slamming.
*In those areas your "it's normal" contractor and your "use silicone" salesmen are correct, it's easier to use something flexible than to try and make these adjacent surfaces rigid enough to avoid cracking.
If your whole house is settling enough to cause cracking grout lines in four months, you'll see signs of that settling elsewhere too.  Starting with the corners of window and door openings.  Tile or no tile.  Let's assume that's not it.
If you don't have either of those two problems, if your grout lines are cracking in random places in the middle of a floor or wall then your problem is not the grout but the preparation of the framing and subsurfaces for the tiling job.  If the shower floor is flexing when you stand on it, or if slamming the door causes vibrations and cracking throughout the shower stall and not just very near the door, all those point to a poor tiling job.   Grout repair will not help.

Thank you! I've added a picture in the original post so it's clearer to understand what I'm talking about. Jay613, what would you recommend doing? The contractor wants me to sign a waiver for using anything that's not the same grout that he used initially. Even assuming the tiling job was done poorly, re-tiling is not really an option at this stage.

Which crack are we talking about?  What is the brown material on the right, is that wood or is it ceramic tile with a wood finish?  Are we talking about just that seam between the brown and grey tile?  It looks like you already used caulk there and that has cracked .... and you say this is all inside of 4 months?? Or  are we talking about the corner bead along the top of the curb, which seems to have come away cleanly from BOTH adjacent tiles, implying that just that piece is moving, IE, not installed correctly?

I'm talikng about the crack that starts from the glass to the edge of the white door frame, which then leaked to the bottom of the step that was initially white and now is brown. There are more cracks inside the shower and outside, between the floor and the step that leads into the shower. Yes, the project was completed in July, and they used caulk, and this is how it looks now and I'm figuring out what needs to be done to solve it.

If water is leaking from the door sill onto the floor outside that's a whole other problem and nothing to do with cracked grout.  Water on top of the sill should drip back into the shower. Water that gets through cracks in the grout, or even through the grout itself, should find its way to the drain, not to the bathroom floor.  That's all part of the design.  It you have THOSE problems, it's a whole new question but I don't think you'll like the answer.  What is the brown wall material?  Wood?

The brown ribbon piece on the left is tile (wood look but there's no wood). That's the wall of the shower. The white-painted piece is the door frame (not the shower door, the bathroom door), made of wood. The glass (top left corner) is the shower door. you're looking at the side of the door that doesn't open, but rotates against the wall. In order to rotate there is a gap of air there. Inside the shower, there's a rubber that blocks the water when the door is shut, but when we get out, or we leave the door open after showering, the water can get in the gap; a bit probably does, that's normal.

What doesn't seem normal is that the grout, just after a few months of use is falling apart. So I'm figuring out why is that (house moving, poor installation, wrong material or something else) and how it can be solved. Does that make sense?

It makes sense.  Closing the bathroom door will vibrate the wall.  It will be hard to keep grout from cracking in the joint between the brown wall and grey floor tile so close to the bathroom door.  A really good tile job will prevent that, but even if everything else was done well, you might get cracked grout there.  Silicone is a good workaround.  This is cosmetic! If water is rolling out of the shower onto the bathroom floor, that is an entirely different problem.   A few drops after the door is open is not a problem, you'll get more than that from condensation.
